# Outlook Signatures

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to create a signature with an image so that the image does not turn into an attachment when emails are sent?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the Source of the email [using view source] and see how the image is embedded. And It is fully depending on the client's email application, as on how it is rendered. Normally , Outlook shows the signature as it is ,for trusted recipients. Gmail too will show it as an attachment if the sender is not trusted.

The only sureshot way is to have ASCII text images...

Answer (score 1):

It is usually dependent on the receivers client, that determines how it comes through